# Layer of graphene on reflector of an antenna

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, conductors, antennas, material-science

First of all I have no idea how well graphene "sticks" to other metals, but let's suppose it does (well, if I may please ask you to reply to the "stick" question too...). Given the material great conductivity, would my reflector act as an electrical perfect plane (well, yeah, it's not an infinite plane, and not even with graphene would be infinitely conductive, but still...)?

In case it would work, considering a reflector made of aluminium, how many dB less you would expect for the back radiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphene is not a superconductor. It's just better than any other element eg Silver. Given how thin a single sheet is, I would expect almost no alteration to the antenna's characteristics. That would, however, depend on the frequency.

Comment: Well in a conductive metal, there is reflection because currents flow parallel to the metal wall itself. So if currents flow better in graphene (currents flow with skin effect), wouldn't it be better? We are talking about frequencies which go from 700MHz to 2700MHz for example

Comment: We are also talking about one atomic layer thickness

Comment: Touché XD Forgot skin effect would affect more atomic layers depending on the frequency.

Does Graphene sticks to any surface though?

Comment: it is very unlikely that a *reflector* antenna's performance is limited by the conductivity of the metal. Much more important to efficiency, back and side lobe levels, is the blockage from the feed and/or struts holding the subreflector.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I didn't mean a patch antenna